# Create a dynamic XML file by taking a sample XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have to create a dynamic XML taking an XML as an example.

E.g.:

```
<root>
     <cde>
          <id1>11</id1>
          <id2>aa3</id2>
          <listProducts>
                <Products>
                     <id>123123</ndg>
                     <Name>AAFFF</Name>
                     <listProductsService>
                          <ProductsService>
                               <id>AA22</id>
                               <numRapp>324554</numRapp>
                          </ProductsService>
                     </listProductsService>
                     <listProcess>
                          <idProcessItem>FDD223</idProcessItem>
                     </listProcess>
                </Products>
          </listProducts>
          <ddd>DSSVDDSS</ddd>
          <dateVar>2022/02/22 12:15:00</dateVar>
     </cde>
     <fgh>
          <id1>AB223</id1>
          <idDoc>AACC4454</idDoc>
          <idAAA>CCCVV223</idAAA>
          <progrVers>1</progrVers>
          <listCF>
                <DescrCF>
                     <id>123456</id>
                     <descr>VVVV</descr>
                     <cgggg>AAAAA</cgggggg>
                </DescrCF>
          </listCF>
          <bbbffd>VVVVV</bbbffd>
          <hhhggg>DDDDDDDD</hhhggg>
     </fgh>
     <cde>
          <id1>55</id1>
          <id2>bbff3</id2>
          <listProducts>
                <Products>
                     <id>123123</ndg>
                     <Name>AAFFF</Name>
                     <listProductsService>
                          <ProductsService>
                               <id>AA22</id>
                               <numRapp>324554</numRapp>
                          </ProductsService>
                     </listProductsService>
                     <listProcess>
                          <idProcessItem>FDD223</idProcessItem>
                     </listProcess>
                </Products>
          </listProducts>
          <ddd>DSSVDDSS</ddd>
          <dateVar>2022/02/22 12:15:00</dateVar>
     </cde>
     <fgh>
          <id>FFFVVGG332</id>
          <idDoc>FFC33</idDoc>
          <idAAA>CCCVV223</idAAA>
          <progrVers>1</progrVers>
          <listCF>
                <DescrCF>
                     <id>123456</id>
                     <descr>VVVV</descr>
                     <cgggg>AAAAA</cgggggg>
                </DescrCF>
          </listCF>
          <bbbffd>VVVVV</bbbffd>
          <hhhggg>DDDDDDDD</hhhggg>
     </fgh>
</root>
```

I have to cycle `<cde>` and `<fgh>` for all the data coming to me. How can I do to create this XML dynamically by cycling them? root must be only one.

Tast thing: the id1 of `<cde>` and `<fgh>` must match in the xml file.

I tried to create a dto model and then loop the data but nothing. I tried to create a dummy JSON but nothing. Do you have any suggestions?

I tried creating a class with all the data:

```
public class root
{
  public cde cde { get; set; }
  public fgh fgh { get; set; }
}

public class cde 
{
  public string id1 { get; set; }
  public string id2 { get; set; }
  public listProducts { get; set; }
}
....
```

to cycle the data:

```
var root = new List<Root>();

for(int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
{
  root.Add(root = new root
  {
    cde = new cde {
     id1 = 11,
     id2 = 222,
     listProducts = new listProducts {
       listProducts = new listProducts 
       {
        ....
       }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

as a final result I get a list.

To create XML I relied on XMLSerialize:

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
Indent = true,
OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
Async = false
}

var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] {XmlQualifiedName.Empty});

Xmlserializer x = new Xmlserializer(root.GetType());

using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\test.xml", settings)
{

  x.Serialize(writer, root, ns);
}
```

but my xml file looks like this:

```
<ArrayOfRoots>
  <root>
     <cde>
          <id1>11</id1>
          <id2>aa3</id2>
          <listProducts>
                <Products>
                     <id>123123</ndg>
                     <Name>AAFFF</Name>
                     <listProductsService>
                          <ProductsService>
                               <id>AA22</id>
                               <numRapp>324554</numRapp>
                          </ProductsService>
                     </listProductsService>
                     <listProcess>
                          <idProcessItem>FDD223</idProcessItem>
                     </listProcess>
                </Products>
          </listProducts>
          <ddd>DSSVDDSS</ddd>
          <dateVar>2022/02/22 12:15:00</dateVar>
     </cde>
     <fgh>
          <id1>AB223</id1>
          <idDoc>AACC4454</idDoc>
          <idAAA>CCCVV223</idAAA>
          <progrVers>1</progrVers>
          <listCF>
                <DescrCF>
                     <id>123456</id>
                     <descr>VVVV</descr>
                     <cgggg>AAAAA</cgggggg>
                </DescrCF>
          </listCF>
          <bbbffd>VVVVV</bbbffd>
          <hhhggg>DDDDDDDD</hhhggg>
     </fgh>
     <cde>
          <id1>55</id1>
          <id2>bbff3</id2>
          <listProducts>
                <Products>
                     <id>123123</ndg>
                     <Name>AAFFF</Name>
                     <listProductsService>
                          <ProductsService>
                               <id>AA22</id>
                               <numRapp>324554</numRapp>
                          </ProductsService>
                     </listProductsService>
                     <listProcess>
                          <idProcessItem>FDD223</idProcessItem>
                     </listProcess>
                </Products>
          </listProducts>
          <ddd>DSSVDDSS</ddd>
          <dateVar>2022/02/22 12:15:00</dateVar>
     </cde>
     <fgh>
          <id>FFFVVGG332</id>
          <idDoc>FFC33</idDoc>
          <idAAA>CCCVV223</idAAA>
          <progrVers>1</progrVers>
          <listCF>
                <DescrCF>
                     <id>123456</id>
                     <descr>VVVV</descr>
                     <cgggg>AAAAA</cgggggg>
                </DescrCF>
          </listCF>
          <bbbffd>VVVVV</bbbffd>
          <hhhggg>DDDDDDDD</hhhggg>
     </fgh>
</root>
<root>
     <cde>
          <id1>11</id1>
          <id2>aa3</id2>
          <listProducts>
                <Products>
                     <id>123123</ndg>
                     <Name>AAFFF</Name>
                     <listProductsService>
                          <ProductsService>
                               <id>AA22</id>
                               <numRapp>324554</numRapp>
                          </ProductsService>
                     </listProductsService>
                     <listProcess>
                          <idProcessItem>FDD223</idProcessItem>
                     </listProcess>
                </Products>
          </listProducts>
          <ddd>DSSVDDSS</ddd>
          <dateVar>2022/02/22 12:15:00</dateVar>
     </cde>
     <fgh>
          <id1>AB223</id1>
          <idDoc>AACC4454</idDoc>
          <idAAA>CCCVV223</idAAA>
          <progrVers>1</progrVers>
          <listCF>
                <DescrCF>
                     <id>123456</id>
                     <descr>VVVV</descr>
                     <cgggg>AAAAA</cgggggg>
                </DescrCF>
          </listCF>
          <bbbffd>VVVVV</bbbffd>
          <hhhggg>DDDDDDDD</hhhggg>
     </fgh>
     <cde>
          <id1>55</id1>
          <id2>bbff3</id2>
          <listProducts>
                <Products>
                     <id>123123</ndg>
                     <Name>AAFFF</Name>
                     <listProductsService>
                          <ProductsService>
                               <id>AA22</id>
                               <numRapp>324554</numRapp>
                          </ProductsService>
                     </listProductsService>
                     <listProcess>
                          <idProcessItem>FDD223</idProcessItem>
                     </listProcess>
                </Products>
          </listProducts>
          <ddd>DSSVDDSS</ddd>
          <dateVar>2022/02/22 12:15:00</dateVar>
     </cde>
     <fgh>
          <id>FFFVVGG332</id>
          <idDoc>FFC33</idDoc>
          <idAAA>CCCVV223</idAAA>
          <progrVers>1</progrVers>
          <listCF>
                <DescrCF>
                     <id>123456</id>
                     <descr>VVVV</descr>
                     <cgggg>AAAAA</cgggggg>
                </DescrCF>
          </listCF>
          <bbbffd>VVVVV</bbbffd>
          <hhhggg>DDDDDDDD</hhhggg>
     </fgh>
</root>
</arrayofroots>
```

multiply all the root but I need only one root and several  and

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do and what you've tried yourself

Comment: I hope to have written properly. If there are still doubts I will try to write better

Comment: Please minimize example to core of the issue to not wasting time trying to see the realm problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml is NOT dynamic, it has a known format.  When an XML file has a schema it is best to create c# classes using xsd.exe and use xml serialization.  But this method is slow and usually leads to classes that have lots of layers and makes it harder to process the data due to number of layers of depth.

My approach is to attempt to flatten the data and use XML Linq (XDocument) to parse the data.  Below are the classes I would use with your Xml.  It appears that you xml tags that contain "list" are not really lists but a singleton from sample provided, but may really be lists.

```
    public class Roots
    {
        public List<Root> roots { get; set; }
    }
    public class Root
    {
        public List<CDE> cde { get; set; }
        public List<FGH> fgh { get; set; }
    }
    public class CDE
    {
        public int id1 { get; set; }
        public string id2 { get; set; }
        public int productID { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public string serviceID { get; set; }
        public string numRapp { get; set; }
        public string idProcessItem { get; set; }
    }
    public class FGH
    {
        public string id1 { get; set; }
        public string idDoc { get; set; }
        public string idAAA { get; set; }
        public int progrVers { get; set; }
        public int productId { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public string productService { get; set; }
        public string serviceId { get; set; }
        public string numRapp { get; set; }
        public string idProcessItem { get; set; }


    }
```